# make max-width columns fluid?

Tags: html, css, grid, fluid-layout

i've got a fluid/responsive column layout such as:

```
.row{
    float:left;
    max-width:960px;
    width:100%;
}

.column{
    float:left;
    margin:0 15px;
}

.column:first-child{
    margin-left:0;
}

.column:last-child{
    margin-right:0;
}

.column.third{
    max-width:300px;
}
```

html:

```
<div clas="row">
    <div class="column third">content</div>
    <div class="column third">content</div>
    <div class="column third">content</div>
</div>
```

it works, but when I resize the window, the columns don't resize, they just stay at their max-width until the window is below their max-width.

Is their a way to get them to resize with the window without using percentages? I want to get away from using percentage widths and margins, as they are (a lot of the time) not a whole pixel actual size and can lead to slight gaps and other things

JS fiddle for where its at so far:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UkhAR/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MUST defined a width on an element before max-width can be calculated, as such simply change your CSS for `.column.third` per the below:

```
.column.third{
    width:100%;
    max-width:300px;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UkhAR/)

[**More from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

> The max-width CSS property is used to set the maximum width of a given
>   element. It prevents the used value of the width property from
>   becoming larger than the value specified for max-width.

Comment: thanks for that info, however the columns still aren't fluid - they stay at their defined max width until the viewing window falls below this value - meaning the columns break layout and go underneath each other between 300 - 959px

Comment: @rpsep you wont be able to accomplish what you want unless you use either calc or % margins

Comment: not the answer I was hoping for, but answered my question :)

Answer (score -1):

use resolution in % not in pixel.

For example use `margin-left 10%` instead `150px`. it may work.